# Problem executing .jar in php

Tags: php, jar, command, execute

I am trying to run a simple `.jar` file in php. The `.jar` is supposed to read a file called `test.txt` and write a file called `test2.txt`.

After creating the jar, I execute `java -jar "C:\wamp\www\Sistem\Sistem\dist\Sistem.jar"` in cmd and it works just fine, the test2.txt is modified, but in php this doesn't happen. Here's the source

**C:\wamp\www\Sistem\index.php**:

```
< ? php
echo exec('java -jar "C:\wamp\www\Sistem\Sistem\dist\Sistem.jar"');
? >
```

I just access `http://localhost/Sistem/`, but the `test2.txt` file does not modify. I really need help, thanks !

Comment: **Sistem** is spelled **System** !

Comment: Try `\\\` instead of `\\` in the path.

Comment: I haven't run php on Windows, but this kind of thing often requires some care with file permissions. The user owning the web server process will probably need write permissions on `test2.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using absolute path to java binary:

```
shell_exec('"c:/program files/oracle/jdk/bin/java.exe" -jar "d:/path/to/jar.jar"');
```

If it will work, that means php runs with different `%PATH%` environment variable.